# File Security on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file, security

Is there some code to prevent direct access to my theme files. I have a vague idea on how I would do it.

```
if(! defined('ABSPATH')){exit}; /*This is the best way right?*/
```

Besides from that are there any other code precautions I need to do to maximise my security?

Comment: What's wrong with someone accessing your theme files directly? The code you posted is gimmicky/pointless in most situations.

Comment: I heard it was used for blocking plugins?

Comment: You should read the selected answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62999/worthwhile-to-restrict-direct-access-of-theme-files

Comment: my theme is using template parts...

Comment: ... *and* it is using global variables from the calling context (parent file), *and* `register_globals` is on, *and* the template part is using these variables without any security check?

Comment: Yes, thats why i am enquiring about securring it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that will be enough but if you want more security then you should make some htaccess work for example :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourwebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov)$ http://yourwebsite.com/ [NC]
```